# How to find the real scale and the true number of rotation and translation by matching the features of two images in monocular camera?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to find the true scale by the two images which is already done the feature matches，and found the homography matrix and also the rotation matrix, translation vector by my monocular camera. What should I do to find the true scale and get the accurate number of my rotation and translation number?

I have already tried to initialize the translation z vector and also tried the triangulation function to solve for the scale problem，but it doesn't work.

Can anyone give me some details, or guide me?

```
vector<DMatch> matches;
FlannBasedMatcher fbmatcher(new flann::LshIndexParams(20, 10, 2));
fbmatcher.match(descriptor_object, descriptor_scene, matches);

double minDist = 100, maxDist = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < descriptor_object.rows; i++)
{
    if (matches[i].distance < minDist)
    {
         minDist = matches[i].distance;
    }
    if (matches[i].distance > maxDist)
    {
        maxDist = matches[i].distance;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < descriptor_object.rows; i++)
{
    if (matches[i].distance <= max(2 * minDist, 30.0))
    {
        matches.push_back(matches[i]);
    }
}

Mat outImg;
drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, matches, outImg,
    Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(), 
    DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
imshow("ORBdemo", outImg);

vector<Point2f> points1;
vector<Point2f> points2;

for (int i = 0; i < (int)matches.size(); i++)
{
    points1.push_back(keypoints1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
    points2.push_back(keypoints2[matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
}

Mat K = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 506.65, 0, 287.29, 0, 506.65, 271.47, 0, 0,1);

Mat R, t;
double focal = 506.65;
Point2d pp = (287.29, 271.47);



Mat H = findHomography(points1, points2,RANSAC,3.0);
recoverPose(H, points1, points2, R, t, focal, pp );


cout << "Homography matrix = " << H << endl;
cout << "rotation estimation" << R << endl;
cout << "translation estimation" << t << endl;
```

I expect the output of translation vector is 250(mm)，but the actual output is 
0.99985345431321 (I don't know the actual units).